# heroku login error rubygems-bundler/wrapper (LoadError) - ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help, I'm trying to deploy a rails app to heroku through the terminal on ubuntu 12.04.
I tried,

```
$ heroku login
```

and got the following message

```
/home/laolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-    1.2.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems-bundler/wrapper (LoadError)
from /home/laolu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.2.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1113:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1113:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1105:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1105:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I'm not sure if it's useful, but here's my gemfile as well

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and was able to solve it.

1. Open your terminal and type:

   which heroku

you should get back something like:
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku

1. Type "sudo gedit /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku"
2. At the top of the file you should see a line similar to:

   "#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9.3"
3. Change to:

   "#!/usr/bin/env ruby"
4. Save
5. Retype in terminal "heroku login" and you should be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

If the file is read-only, you may save using code below:

```
:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null
```